# Node-red: do not render the web page

Tags: node-red

My project needs to show some weather data in a web page.
I build the following schema:
[image]

When I request the /gateway/pos URL a OpenWeatherMap request is done, and, if the returned code 'cod' is '200', i build a web page with some data.
In this way the browser show me the html code (as an text editor).
If I remove the 'http request', the page is rendered correctly.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message emitted by the `http request` node includes a property that contains the HTTP response headers. This is called `msg.headers`.

The `http response` node also uses this property to set the HTTP headers of the response to the original request. This is the cause of the unexpected behaviour.

You should add a `change` node and delete the `msg.headers` property after the `http request` node.